# Content to share in Facebook is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to share content in facebook, but when the dialog of Facebook appears, the content to share it's empty I mean nothing is showing up, did I forgot to write something in the code? or something else? Hope you can help me.

- (IBAction)ShareFacebook:(id)sender {

  ```
  NSLog(@"Boton touched");

  FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
  FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc]init];
  [content setContentDescription:  @"https://www.xxxxx.com"];
  [content setContentTitle:  @"https://www.xxxxxxx.com"];
  //[content setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString: nil]];

  [shareDialog setMode:FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic];
  [shareDialog setShareContent:content];
  [shareDialog setFromViewController:self];
  [shareDialog show];
  ```

  }

Comment: You can not specify any properties such as title, description, thumbnail dynamically at the time of sharing any more.

Comment: Thanks, I've already read the updated document of Facebook about this properties, we can't use them anymore Thanks. :)